# Could not copy the file "BoDi.dll" because it was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, specflow

I'm using Specflow in my ASP.Net Core(v3) project to write UTs for Azure Data Factory pipelines. These are the packages that I've installed for the same:

[image]

When I build the solution I get the below error:
`Could not copy the file "C:\Users\DDC\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.0.255\tools\netcoreapp3.1\BoDi.dll" because it was not found.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the same issue by adding BoDi to packages.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the BoDi NuGet package in your test project. Open the NuGet package command line and run this command, or install it through the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio. Just make sure the package gets installed in the test project.

```
Install-Package BoDi
```

SpecFlow used to have BoDi bundled with it, but it is just referenced as another NuGet package.

Comment: That was a solution for my case

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to a later version of SpecRun.SpecFlow, I had trouble with versions before 3.1. You're on 3.0.255. Update to the latest stable and see what you get.

You may need to upgrade the SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation package too.